# design a decorator to write a function return value in a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

decorator should be like

```
@log_message
def a_function_that_returns_a_string():
    return "a string"
@log_message
def a_function_that_returns_a_strings_with_a_newline(s):
    return "{}\n".format(s)
```

my implementation is something like that,buts not writting anything in file,i am new to decorators

```
 def log_message(func):
          def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
              result = func(a)
              with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
                 for row in results:
                     f.write("%s\n" % str(row))
              return result
          return wrapper
```

Comment: It seems you just copied the assignment you got and now are assigning it to us...

Comment: @mrCarnivore i don't  understand the logic of decorators can u tell me where its wrong

Comment: Remember to open the file in append mode. Otherwise, previous results will be lost. (Is this homework? There is a logger module in Python that is designed for doing what you want ...)

Comment: Finally, the `for row in results` expects an iterator. Are you sure about your return type? Try to see how you can improve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were not far off:
`result = func(a)` needs to be `result = func(*args, **kwargs)`.

This prints to screen. Writing to file is almost the same:

```
def log_message(func):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(result)
        return result

    return wrapper


@log_message
def a_function_that_returns_a_string():
    return "a string"

@log_message
def a_function_that_returns_a_strings_with_a_newline(s):
    return "{}\n".format(s)


a = a_function_that_returns_a_string()
b = a_function_that_returns_a_strings_with_a_newline('abc')
```

Comment: we are not sending any list of values or dict in func we are sending a simple string why we are catching it in args or kwargs

Comment: `*args` catches all arguments (of any form) given to call of wrapper. `**kwargs` catches all keyword arguments (e.g. of form key='abc) passed to wrapper. You need to pass the exact arguments to func. Otherwise the arguments will get lost.

Comment: there is not need to return result if i am mistaken right

Comment: You have to return the result. Otherwise you decorated function will not return anything.